# Display markdown without having to use v-html

Tags: html, vue.js, npm, xss

I have a "blog" kind of website, where users can post new blogs with a WYSIWYG, and then have them displayed on the website.

The thing is I want it to be XSS safe and I don't want to use `v-html` or `.innerHTML` at all - is that possible?

The most obvious way is not to use HTML at all when posting a blog - I was thinking about using markdown instead. But parsing and displaying markdown means having to use `.innerHTML` anyway:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
      marked('# Marked in the browser\n\nRendered by **marked**.');
  </script>
```

Is there a way to do it completely without `v-html`?

Comment: i recomment you to use some WYSIWYG editor, this editors have the input and viewer components for you use as simple way. take a look in this projects they are very usefull. https://www.vuescript.com/best-wysiwyg-rich-text-editor/

Comment: in my project i have used the tiptap, works fine in Nuxt.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some user content displayed inside the browser, which works only with HTML (also images etc. but that's not very useful for blog articles). Which means `v-html` is your only choice...

`v-html` is not evil, problem is what you put inside. Markdown doesn't save you here as it [allows inline HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html)

So the only way is to [sanitize user content](https://github.com/markedjs/marked#usage).

As the content is created once and displayed multiple times, it makes sense to do this MD -> HTML transformation + sanitization only once when user is saving new article, save the result somewhere and later used it as a content for `v-html`